Lightning channel opening stuck - Alby Hub
I opened my second lightning channel (only receiving capacity) on Alby Hub (on StartOS) and it's been stuck in "opening" for almost 12hr. I tried to see the "funding transaction" I tracked the funding transaction on mempool and it has a 1.01 sats/vb. Is there a way to speed it up or cancel it (I paid the channel opening over LN)?
